# Get Incremental Number from two loops

Tags: javascript, math, for-loop

i have two simple regular `for` loops.

```
for (var i=0; i<images.xAxis.length; i++){
  for (var x=0; x<images.yAxis.length; x++){
    //return number from 0 to 9
    imgNumber = images.xAxis.length*i+x;
    addImage(imgNumber);
  }
}
```

Well it is **not** returning number from 0 to 9. 
instead it returning :

```
1
2
3
-
2
4
6
-
3
6
9
```

Assuming that i don't want to use helper variable like:

```
idx+=1;
```

i want to use `x` and `i` in some math expression.

Thanks!

Comment: actually the code is far more complicated. i just did a simple concept, so you get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are basically trying to do with those nested loops is, how to convert a number in base 3 to a number in base 10. The way to do it is:

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
  for (var x=0; x<3; x++){
   //return number from 0 to 9
     addImage(3*i+x);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
With your edit, the code becomes

```
for (var x=0; x<images.xAxis.length; x++){
  for (var y=0; y<images.yAxis.length; y++){
    //return number from 0 to 9
    imgNumber = images.xAxis.length*i+x;
    addImage(imgNumber);
  }
}
```

Comment: i don't know if it helps. because `3` is just example. i will update question. please see.

Comment: If you use n instad of 3, things don't change, just put n instead of all the 3 in my code ( invcluding as addImage argument)

Comment: there was however a little problem. when it finishes fill up the first row i had `x=1` and `y=0` so it tried to multiple `40*1+0` weich got me the number 40 again. what i did is `for (var y=1; y<images.yAxis.length+1; y++) .....`

Answer (score 1):

You can try using:-

```
 for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
   for (var x=0; x<3; x++){
      imgNumber = i * 3 + x;
      addImage(imgNumber);
    }
 }
```